# How to extract all values from an enum an add them to a List<String>

Tags: java, generics, enums

The title is pretty self-explanatory. Here's my code so far:

```
public List<String> getVoucherStatuses() {
        List<String> listOfStatuses = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (VoucherStatus status : VoucherStatus.values()) {
            listOfStatuses.add(status.name());
        }
        return listOfStatuses;
    }
```

and here is the Enum:

```
public enum VoucherStatus {
        GENERATED, INVALID, ISSUED, REDEEMED, EXPIRED
    }
```

I keep getting null reference expcetion. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Which line is getting `NullPointerException`?

Comment: where are you getting the exception?

Comment: Where do you define the `name()` method?

Comment: Just run it without exceptions - your problem is somewhere else...

Comment: @LouisWasserman that comes with the Enum class.

Comment: Also are you sure you want to use `name()` and not `toString()`? See javadoc for the difference.

Comment: @assylias - I misread your comment as "[You should] just run it without exceptions", as if it were as simple as turning off asserts.  `-Djava.bugs.enabled=false` perhaps? :)

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle That would be a real cool feature! or maybe not!

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle A C++ version of a program I used to work on had a "flicker free" option. It was suggested we add a "no bugs" option as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling this from within the static initialiser of the enum, it wont have finished initialising which may well give you an NPE.

One work around is to use a nested class for the static.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? how can we call this from within the static initializer of the Enum?

Comment: @why-el Off the top of my head: In the constructors of the enum constants. In initialiser expressions of other statics in the enum. In an explicit static initialiser of the enum. In the initialisation of an implemented interface.